# How to prove $2\sqrt{n+a}-2\sqrt{n+a+1}+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n+1}}>0$ for $\frac{1}{2}<a<1$ and $n>\frac{1}{16a-8}$

Tags: calculus, analysis

This is a part of the problem: prove the sequence $$x_{n}=1+\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}+...+\frac{1}{\sqrt{n}}-2\sqrt{n+a}$$ strictly increase for $a>\frac{1}{2}$ and $n>\frac{1}{16a-8}$

I have tried induction, and analysis the difference term as functions, but unable to fully use the constraints and get the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may want to check my algebra, but the inequality can be rewritten
as 
$$
\frac 1{\sqrt {n+1}}>\frac 2{\sqrt{a+n+1}+\sqrt{a+n}}$$
which is equivalent (after clearing denominators and squaring manifestly positive numbers) to
$$
2a+2n+1+2\sqrt{(a+n)(a+n+1)} > 4n+4.
$$
This is further equivalent to 
$$
\sqrt{(a+n)(a+n+1)} > n-a+\frac 32
$$
which would follow (since the left hand side is positive and the right hand side may or may not be positive) from
$$
(a+n)(a+n+1) > n^2+n(3-2a)+(a-\frac 32)^2
$$
which is in turn equivalent to 
$$
n(4a-2)>-4a+\frac 94.
$$
This works out to be $$n>\frac {-16a+9}{16a-8}=-1+\frac 1{16a-8}.$$
So it would follow from the inequality given (or rather, you will see that you have an increase provided that $n+1>\frac 1{16a-8}$ (it is a bit of a matter of semantics where you would say that the increase begins).